# Use amp-img tag in place of img tag for images - Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, accelerated-mobile-page

I am working on creating a Sphinx theme based on Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP). While creating it, I came to realize that since AMP uses `amp-img` tag in place of the `img` tag. Is there a way to convert all the img tag in the sphinx generated docs to amp-img

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box. The easiest option is to post-process your HTML output from Sphinx.